# Create read replica with only specified list of tables

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

I have a MySQL instance (running on the latest version of the 5.7 engine) and I would like to create a read replica from it in the same region (if not possible, other regions might work as well) but only with the reduced set of tables.

I've tried using [replication filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_MySQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html#USER_MySQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.ReplicationFilters) but I ended up with the full db copy after which operations against db entities specified in replication filters `replicate-do-db` and `replicate-do-table` work.

I thought that they can be used to do the following like it is stated in the official documentation:

- To reduce the size of a read replica. With replication filtering, you can exclude the databases and tables that aren't needed on the read replica.
- To exclude databases and tables from read replicas for security reasons.
- To replicate different databases and tables for specific use cases at different read replicas. For example, you might use specific read replicas for analytics or sharding.

Is such a thing even possible or do I need to try something else? I'm aware of the existence of DMS, but I would like to explore the possibility of creating a read-replica-native solution.

Since source db is a few terabytes large and read replica will only weigh a couple of gigabytes, I would like to avoid any solutions that would need to reserve more storage than needed because it could be costly in my case.

Update

These are combinations I tried. Since it isn't possible to set different parameter group for MySQL read replica in the same region, I created parameter group, attached it to the source and then created replica.

*Test case 1:* `replicate-do-db = test` + `replica-do-table = test.test_1,test.test_2`

*Test case 2:* `replica-do-table = test.test_1,test.test_2`

As I mentioned, 4 dbs running on that RDS instance were replicated in both scenarios even though I specified only one db or set of tables for that db.

Comment: Can you show us how you set these configurations?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set these configurations?

Comment: Code is my original comment and is specified in parameters under the parameter group attached to the read replica instance where replicate-do-x is the name of the parameter and test or test.test_1 is its value

Comment: All other parameters are the same as the default param group.